# Rails Tutorial 2.2: Puma Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, puma

I'm trying to learn Rails from the Rails Tutorial book, got lubuntu so I could try to get the best experience possible. Now I'm stuck on something that should be easy and straight forward.

We're creating a little "toy app" a very basic twitter like thing, still at the very beginning, we used:

```
$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

To generate a User Table if I'm not mistaken and then:

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

I guess to update a preexisting table structure (not sure, but it's said that later everything will be explained).

Finally we are supposed to run this:

```
 $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

In a differente tab, I did and got this error:

```
~/workspace/toy_app$ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://-p:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://-p:3000
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:255:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:255:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:255:in `add_tcp_listener'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:102:in `block in parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:85:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:85:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:129:in `load_and_bind'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/single.rb:84:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:51:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:296:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zero/workspace/toy_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/zero/workspace/toy_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/zero/workspace/toy_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Is anything corrupted? Did I do anything wrong? I went to check the files I remembered seeing puma (in the app folder) on and it's in the gem file:

```
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
```

And the puma.rb file (took out the comments):

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

plugin :tmp_restart
```

I was going to put all the files mentioned but it's tons of code, if there's any that's useful I'll post it, I don't want to spam with possible useless code.

Answer (score 1):

`$IP` is not defined in your environment, so `rails server` is trying to use `-p` as the IP address. Try this:

```
rails server -b ${IP:-127.0.0.1} -p ${PORT:-3000}
```

Alternatively, set these environment variables with `export` before running `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT`:

```
export IP=127.0.0.1
export PORT=3000
```

Or if you're fine with Rails' defaults, just forget all this and run `rails server`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running locally you should be able to use `rails server` without arguments. If you are using the Hartl tutorial, it presumes you are using a web-based IDE that requires the extra arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cloud based IDE`, you need to listen at `particular IP & PORT`. For example, `C9`, you need to listen to `0.0.0.0 and 8080`. So they have setup `environment variables, $IP & $PORT.`

If you execute,

```
echo $IP  ###gives 0.0.0.0
echo $PORT ###gives 8080

rails s -b $IP -p $PORT  ##Rails x.x.x application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

The `-b` option binds Rails to the specified IP, by default it is localhost.

If you are on your local machine, run

```
rails s ### Rails x.x.x application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
```